# Voltage between A and B

Tags: circuit-analysis

Can anyone explain to me how to calculate the voltage between A and B in this circuit please?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let the *bottom* node be GND. Then you have to realize that both voltage sources (batteries) are reversed in respect to each other. That means: \$A>0,B<0\$.

In the circuit you have two voltage dividers. One composed of the 25k and 47k, the other 10k and 33k.

Now, the rule of thumb for voltage dividers comes from Ohm's law. The voltage across a resistor is proportional to the current through that resistor. When you have two resistors in series, they share the same current. By rearranging Ohm's law for both R1 and R2, then substituting, you get the magical expression for voltage dividers:

\$V_{mid} = V_{top} * \frac{R_{lower}}{R_{upper} + R_{lower}}\$

Note that it only applies if there is no extra current drawn from the middle node.

Using that in your case gives the following:

- \$V_A=100V*\frac{47k}{47k+25k}\$
- \$V_B=-100V*\frac{33k}{33k+10k}\$

Then we simply subtract these from each other (in the desired order):

- \$V_{AB} = V_A-V_B\$

I'll leave the arithmetic as an exercise to the reader.
Also, you might wanna lookup theory on voltage dividers.

---

I hope it's right...

Comment: That should be \$V_{AB}=V_A-V_B\$

Comment: Yes, you're right. Ill correct it.

Comment: This is NOT a 'complaint' but a comment. Your willingness to help them is appreciated and this is more a thought about how far you go on questions like this.  The answer is arguably a bit too complete for a "homework type question". It's good to show them how, but the end result is almost "plug into calculator" level. While they may take your answer and learn from it, the essential Vmid =  Vtop x Rlower/(Rupper + Rlower) is presented as a completed "black box" and may not be understood. MANY beginners have substantial trouble understanding this at first. Again - comment only. RM

Comment: @RussellMcMahon so how much of an answer is the "right" amount to give? Sounds like a classic case of "[I'll know it when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)"

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I see your point. However I personally prefer this _example-driven teaching/learning_. I believe that making someone force through the process of discovering a wheel doesn't necessarily teach him - simply because of the hatred of the subject.

Comment: What you have given is a "model answer" apart from plugging in the numbers. There is no reason that he will understand how the dividers work - MANY people don't. Hatred plays no part init. He asked HOW to calculate the answer - what he got was "what happens when you calculate it" - it is nearly certain that the "how" has not been conveyed. Certainly the  information is presented in the equations - but many students cannot make the required jump.

Comment: @hoosierEE - see if you know this then:-). There is no right-right answer BUT the one I commented on did not in fact EXPLAIN as requested. It served up an end result with no explanation. A problem is that once one is experienced in such things it is hard to see how beginners cannot understand something if you present it in final form. A "better" [tm] answer MIGHT eg say [And this is a skeleton only that needs fleshing out] . V drop across a resistors is proportional to current -> V = IR. ...

Comment: ... Current in upper and lower resistors is the same so voltages across each is proportional to its resistance. Voltage across whole string is proportional to Rupper + Rlower. Voltage across lower R is proportional to R lower. So portion of total V across Rlower is the fraction of Rlower wrt Rwhole. So Vout = (Rlower/Rwhole) x Vin. QED. **BUT** you need to do this line by line and precept by precept. It's VERY easy to lose the inexperienced.

Comment: So why don't you answer the question yourself? ;)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon good point. The tricky thing for answerers is inferring from the question how much of the big picture is actually needed (contrast with how much is asked for!)